# Multi level columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to have multilevel columns, the same way a pivot table can have multiple levels? So for example, you would have a table with months from January to December, but the months would also have a category called quarters 1-4 ?

I do not want a pivot table. I want to be able to edit the data.

[image: example image]

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output? It would be easy to create new columns based on other column data. But impossible to determine if that works in this case.

Comment: I have added a picture of the table. But I want to be able to add rows and filters to the table. "hard coding" is not an option

Comment: Where are the "quoters" categories in your example image?

Comment: That's the table data? That looks like a pivot of data. Why don't you want a pivot table? You can filter refresh easily. Also, it's `quarters` not `quoters`. It's still not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Again, show what you have, and what you desire.

Comment: Did you need the dependent dropdown list? https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/#:~:text=1%20Select%20the%20cell%20where%20you%20want%20the,contains%20the%20main%20drop%20down.%2014%20Click%20OK.